# how do you commission a machine in MAAS from the CLI without running any hardware tests?

Tags: maas

You can commission a machine in MAAS from the CLI with this command:

`maas <profile> machine commission ${SYSTEM_ID}`

how do you run this command but tell MAAS to not run any hardware tests (node-scripts) or to specify a custom set of tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to commission a single existing machine without running any hardware tests, the CLI command is:

`maas <profile> machine commission <system_id> testing_scripts=none`

If you want to disable hardware tests from running when new machines are added to MAAS, you need to remove the "commissioning" tag from all node-scripts.  By default only one script (smartctl-validate) is tagged to be run during commissioning.  You can see all scripts, and their tags, using:

`maas <profile> node-scripts read`

Assuming typical installation where "smartctl-validate" has a script id = 1, and default tags of "storage,commissioning", you can remove commissioning using:

`maas <profile> node-script update 1 tags=storage`

That command will leave the "storage" tag, but remove the "commissioning" tag from the "smartctl-validate" script.

A word of caution: hardware tests can be helpful/useful.  Disabling the tests might not be a good idea.  We disable them because false-positive results (we think due to S.M.A.R.T. drive monitoring) cause our commissionings to hang and fail.